# when importing a function in a different file, the function produces less output

Tags: python, python-import, spyder, global

In one file (function_general) I created an function called process_excel.
This has as input an Excel file path and a list of dictionaries.
As output I have dataframes, the same amount of the length of the list, named based on the contents of the list.

When I import this function in a different file, I receive an list of dataframes, without names.
I work in spyder.

file function_general

```
def process_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name, result_list):
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name, header=3)
    df['GC Injection'] = pd.to_numeric(df['GC Injection'], errors='coerce')
    df = df[~df['GC Injection'].isin(['Maximum', 'Average', 'Minimum', 'Standard Deviation', 'Relative Standard Deviation'])]
    variable = [b.get("experiment").replace(' ','_') + "_data" for b in result_list]
    
    for index, value in enumerate(result_list):
        dhp_test = df[(df['GC Injection'] >= value['Start Injection Number']) & 
                      (df['GC Injection'] <= value['End Injection Number'])]
        dhp_test = dhp_test.reset_index(drop=True)

        # Adding the 'minutes reaction' column
        dhp_test['minutes reaction'] = value['Start Minutes'] + 10 * dhp_test.index
        dhp_test['minutes reaction'] = dhp_test.pop(dhp_test.columns[-1])
        dhp_test.insert(3,"minutes",dhp_test['minutes reaction'])
        dhp_test.drop(['min'],axis = 1, inplace = True)
        dhp_test.drop(['minutes reaction'],axis = 1, inplace = True)       

        globals()[variable[index]] = dhp_test
    
    return [globals()[var] for var in variable] here
```

this gives multiple dataframes

```
from function_general import process_excel
result_dataframes = process_excel(excel_file_path, "GC", injections_list)
```

this gives an list of dataframes, I want the same output as in the function_general file

I copied and pasted the code for the process_excel function in the new file. Which yielded the same results as in function_general, however I want to be able to import the code in other files.

Comment: Why the calls to `globals()`?

Comment: @Friedrich i'm new to coding, id did this because i thought the dataframe would rewrite itself in the loop, wich would result in only one dataframe, instead of 8, i don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: Better to use a dictionary to name items than try to mess about with creating globals like that. See [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @JonSG thanks, this seemed to work, can you explain why?